# How to get Automation testing results of Drupal contributed module through Drupal.org rest API?

Tags: 9, community-official-site

I am trying to get automated testing results of contributed modules through https://www.drupal.org/drupalorg/docs/apis/rest-and-other-apis.

I am able to get nid and vid of any contributed module through the node info API.

And I want to access DrupalCI jobs: pift_ci_job.json or pift_ci_job.xml

Which returns a specific job: [https://www.drupal.org/api-d7/pift_ci_job/[jobid].json](https://www.drupal.org/api-d7/pift_ci_job/%5Bjobid%5D.json)

But, there is nowhere mentioned of `jobid` required for getting the automation testing results, can anyone tell me if there is any way for getting `jobid` of a contributed module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.drupal.org/api-d7/pift_ci_job.json returns a list of all the DrupalCI tests, in the same way https://www.drupal.org/api-d7/node.json returns a list of all the nodes.

That's the only way to get a list of the tests associated to an issue because there isn't a comment/node field for tests, which would otherwise be returned in https://www.drupal.org/api-d7/node/3220733.json (the RESTWS URL for [[PHP8] Tests are failing in PHP 8 / Drupal 9.2.x](https://www.drupal.org/node/3220733)) or https://www.drupal.org/api-d7/comment/14145081.json (the RESTWS URL for [comment #3](https://www.drupal.org/project/microcontent/issues/3220733#comment-14145081) in that issue).

The information about tests shown in the attached file table is added by the [Project issue file test](https://www.drupal.org/project/project_issue_file_test) in [`pift_nodechanges_file_changes_element_alter()`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/project_issue_file_test/-/blob/7.x-3.x/pift.nodechanges.inc#L14).

You can filter the job list, though. For example, you could filter by:

- The issue node ID
  https://www.drupal.org/api-d7/pift_ci_job.json?issue_nid=3220733
- The ID for the user who added it
  https://www.drupal.org/api-d7/pift_ci_job.json?uid=314289
- The environment used for the job
  https://www.drupal.org/api-d7/pift_ci_job.json?environment=php5.4_mysql5.5